# Pairing events based on a session counter and finding the time delta in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, session, events

I have read many SO questions that involve pairing records in SQL but none using a session counter like this.  I have simplified a generic instance of the problem that should be very applicable to many.

Essentially I have a mySQL table recording individual events with a timestamp and an incrementing "session counter" that resets to 0 with every new session, like so:

```
time  counter
t0    0
t1    1
t2    2
t3    0
t4    1
t5    0
t6    1
t7    2
t8    3
t9    4
```

I'd like to take that data and pair the first and last timestamps of every session (and eventually, calculate the time delta) into 1 row per session.  So the desired output would be something like this:

```
start  counter  end  counter
t0     0        t2   2
t3     0        t4   1
t5     0        t9   4
```

I've read some solutions using LEAD and LAG functions, but that's not available in MySQL and the alternative implementations are beyond my level of comprehension.  I know I can brute-force this in Excel / Python, but is there a relatively simple mySQL query that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emulate LEAD function in MySQL using [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Here is the one example

```
select min(time),max(time),count(*)-1
from
(
select time,counter,
if(@prev>counter,@grp:=@grp+1,@grp:=@grp),
@grp as GRPvalue,
@prev:=counter 
from t,(select @prev:=0,@grp:=0) as t1 
order by time
) t2
GROUP BY GRPValue
order by min(time)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a539b/11)

Or here is another SQL query. Here we define group as a count of `counter=0` before current record (if all intervals start  with 0):

```
select min(time),max(time),count(*)-1
from t t1
group by 
(select count(*) from t where t.time<=t1.time and counter = 0)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a539b/16)